# How can I run batch script from linux on windows servers using nmap?

Tags: java, linux, nmap

I'm trying to run batch scripts from linux on a windows machine
I heard the nmap has a solution but I can't get an example
Is it possible? How?
Noam

Answer (score 1):

Nmap (a network scanning tool) is **not** for running Unix/Linux scripts on Windows. On Linux, the usual shell is [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). If you want to run bash scripts on Windows, you might use [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/), you might try [Windows Services for Unix](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=274) or even [win-bash](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/).